# How to close AndroidBarSherlock's SearchView after after clicking search button

Tags: java, android, searchview

I use com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView from AndroidBarSherlock. Everything works fine except SearchView closing. I don't know how to close SearchView's text area after clicking search search button. I can close SearchView's text component only via back button of my phone. Is it possible to close AndroidBarSherlock SearchView's text component by clicking outside SearchView ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have already set onQueryTextChange listener,

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String key) {
        //do your stuff
        hideSoftKeyBoard();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String key) {
        //whatever
        return true;
    }
);
```

hiding keyvoard,

```
private void hideSoftKeyBoard() {
    InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
}
```